# How to prove similarity of a constructed triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

There is a triangle $ABC$ and a point $X$ inside it. The lines $AX$, $BX$, and $CX$ intersect the circumcircle of the triangle $ABC$ also at points $P$, $Q$, and $R$. Let $U$ be a point on the line segment $XP$ so that it is in between the points $X$ and $P$. Let's assume a line, that goes through $U$ and is parallel to $AB$, intersects the line segment $XQ$ at point $V$. Let's also assume that there's a line going through $U$, that is parallel to $CA$, and intersects the line segment $XR$ at point $W$.

Prove that triangles $ABC$ and $UWV$ are similar.

A picture of the situation[image]

Now, here's some things I have noticed/tried:

First of all, it's fairly obvious that the angle $\angle U$ in $\triangle UWV$ is congruent to angle $\angle A$ from the "same" parallel lines/the parallelogram formed. So, the similarity would be proved if we can find one of the other angles in $\triangle UWV$ or if we can find the side lengths of that triangle in terms of the original one, but the latter seems almost impossible to do, so I decided to go angle chasing.

I'm sure that this is possible by chasing angles but everytime I was close to proving $\angle XWV=\angle WCB$ (as the other part of $\angle UWX$ is congruent to $\angle ACW$) I found out that some angle was missing and couldn't find that one in terms of the parts of the angles of the original triangle.

So, I gave up on angle chasing and thought of a different way to prove this. (Well, what follows is essentially angle chasing) If we construct the line segment $QR$, we get the quadrilateral $RWVQ$.

Here's a picture of that situation:[image]

If now the two triangles are actually similar, it follows that $RWVQ$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, as $\angle RQV=\angle RCB$ and as $AB\parallel VU$ and $AC\parallel WU$ then $BC\parallel WV$, which means that $\angle CWV=\angle WCB$ and thus $\angle VWR=\pi-\angle CWV=\pi-\angle WCB$ and so $\angle VWR+\angle QVW=\pi-\angle WCB+\angle WCB=\pi$. And thus if $RWVQ$ were a cyclic quadrilateral then $\angle CWV=\angle WCB$ and as also $\angle UWX=\angle ACW$ then the triangles would be similar.

So, if we could prove that the point $R$, $W$, $V$, and $Q$ were on the same circle, then the triangles would be similar. But I feel this is more difficult than our original questions but I thought it would be wisest to put everything I've thought so far to this.

So, if you have any ideas on how to do this, I would appreciate any hints as I would like to solve it on my own, but right now I'm honestly stuck so I need a nudge in the right direction. (Probably I'm just overthinking the whole question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarity of $XUV$ and $XAB$ gives $XU/XA=UV/AB$.

Similarity of $XUW$ and $XAC$ gives $XU/XA=UW/AC$.

Therefore $UV/UW = AB/AC$.

I'm not sure what the points $P,Q,R$ and the circumscribed circle are for.

Comment: First of all thank you. But I'd say they're for nothing as I think this is an edited question my teacher made (the original one was harder apparently).

Clearly I overthought the whole problem.